# How to cut, copy, paste any listview item in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
 {
     if (listView1.Items[i].Selected)
     {
         listView1.Items[i].Remove();
     }
 }
```

This function simply deletes the selected item in listview.. but i want to cut it and paste it somewhere else.

Comment: Paste it into another listview or what? And that code will remove multiple items if selected, what would you want to do with the clipboard then.

Comment: Actually i am making file browser for window and using treeview control. there are multiple files in a directory i want to cut one file. which is actually one listview item, and paste it to another directory.

Comment: You can't paste a ListViewItem into a directory.  Perhaps consider just copying the name of the file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove the selected listitems and move them to another listview.

```
ListView sourceListView = new ListView();
ListView destListView = new ListView();

var selected = sourceListView.Items
                              .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                              .Where(x => x.Selected)
                              .ToList();

foreach (var item in selected)
{
    sourceListView.Items.Remove(item);
    destListView.Items.Add(item);
}
```